# How to geometrically interpret a 3x3 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was given exams revision exercises and in there is an exercise about matrices and linear algebra. In the exercise, there is a given matrix

$$A =
\begin{pmatrix}
7 & -8 & 8 \\
-6 & 9 & -8 \\
-12 & 16 & -15 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and the first task is to find the eigenvalues and eigenspaces of the matrix (which I know how to compute). However, in the second task, it is asked to "give a geometrical interpretation of the matrix $A$". But how do I know that? In the answers sheet, it's only written "The matrix $A$ produces a symmetry related to the plane $3x-4y+4z=0$ in the direction of the vector $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}-1\\1\\2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.", but I don't understand why and how I can know that.

I have tried searching for help on Google but found nothing. The math theory book I have only shows basic examples of geometrical interpretations of $2{\times}2$ matrices, such as rotations and scaling.

My question is, how to geometrically interpret a $3{\times}3$ matrix ? How can I know a random matrix $A$ produces, for example, a symmetry on the plane $\pi$, or a projection on $Im(A)$ in the direction of $ker(A)$, or a dilation of ratio 2 on $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, or whatever projection, dilation, scaling, rotation, etc. ?

PS: Sorry if some terms sound weird or are incorrect, I speak French.

Comment: Find $A^2$   and $A^3$

Comment: @WillJagy What do I get when I do that?

Comment: Can you compute and state the eigenvalues and eigenspaces? The geometric interpretation follows from there. $\quad$ In particular, if $ \lambda = 1$, then that eigenspace is invariant. If $\lambda =-1$, that eigenspace will be reflected.  What can we say if $\lambda = 2$?

Comment: @CalvinLin The eigenvalues are $\lambda = 1$ (mult. 2) and $\lambda = -1$. Also, do you mean if there is an eigenvalue equal to -1, there is a symmetry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix $$A =
\begin{pmatrix}
7 & -8 & 8 \\
-6 & 9 & -8 \\
-12 & 16 & -15
\end{pmatrix}$$

has the following eigenvalues : $1,1,-1$ with associated eigenvectors

$$V_1=
\begin{pmatrix}
4\\
3\\
0
\end{pmatrix}, \ 
V'_1=\begin{pmatrix}
4\\
0\\
-3
\end{pmatrix}, \ V_{-1}\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\
1\\
2
\end{pmatrix}$$

which means

$$AV_1=1V_1, \ AV'_1=1V_1, \ AV_{-1}=-1V_{-1}\tag{1}$$

Please note

- that the coordinates $x,y,z$ of $V_1$ and $V'_1$ are such that $3x-4y+4z=0$ ; therefore,  as $V_1$ and $V'_1$ are non-proportional, they constitute a basis of this plane,
- and that $V_{-1}$ is the mentionned vector.

Now let us consider a general vector $V \in \mathbb{R^3}$ ; it can be decomposed into the sum of a vector $W$ of the plane $W=aV_{1}+bV'_1$ plus a vector proportionnal to $V_{-1}$ :

$$AV=A(aV_1+bV_2+cV_{-1})=aAV_1+bAV_2+cAV_{-1}=$$

which gives, using (1) :

$$A(aV_1+bV_2+cV_{-1})=aV_1+bV_2-cV_{-1}$$

which is the definition of a symmetry matrix with respect to a certain plane in the direction of a certain vector.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer! I now understand why there is a symmetry. But what about other kind of transformations on any matrices? How can I find them?

Comment: There are very few matrices that can be characterized like that : if for example you have eigenvalues $-1,-1,-1$ with 3 independent eigenvectors, you get a symmetry with respect to the origin (every vector is changed into its opposite). In the case of {1,-1,-1}, it is an axial symmetry. Other (very different) matrices have a geometrical interpretation ; still by a characterization by their eigenvalues : a rotation matrix has eigenvalues $1,e^{i \theta},e^{-i \theta}$ where the eigenvector associated with $1$ is the rotation axis, and $\theta$ the rotation angle.

Comment: Ohhhh, I get it. Thanks a lot! In my previous exercises I also had matrices that produce a "projection on something" or "dilation". How do you find that out as well?

Comment: About projections a) onto a plane characterized by eigenvalues list $0,1,1$ b) onto a line eigenvalue $0,0,1$. Dilation by factor $3$ for example : eigenvalue list $3,3,3$.

Comment: Woah, ok I get it now. Thanks a lot again, I'm very grateful for your help! I sadly don't have enough rep on this site to upvote your answer, but I will mark it as accepted.